# VBA SQL Connection and Query

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I try to make connection with my database through VBA because using pivot table connection takes like 2 minutes (connecting and importing the data). In another job i had the vba code to connect to databse and do mdx query and it was much faster then by using excel pivot table. In this case i can't have mdx query because its not available (different database?).

I have found the code to connect and do query. The problem is i dont get any information if im connected or not and the query part gives me error: (run time error '-2147217865 (80040e37) Automation Error).

Here is the code:

```vb
Sub SQL_Connection()

Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim query As String
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strCon As String

'http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/11/sql-connection-string/

strCon = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=sql2\bbqsrv;Initial Catalog=Reports;Integrated Security=SSPI"

'---  Open   the above connection string.

con.Open (strCon)
con.CommandTimeout = 120 'sec

'---  Now connection is open and you can use queries to execute them.
'---  It will be open till you close the connection

'slq query
query = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [Reports]"

'Performs the actual query
rs.Open query, con

'Dumps all the results from the query into cell A2 of the first sheet in the active workbook
Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub
```

First, can you guys help me how to check if im acutally connected and this part of code works? In excel if i check in DATA>Connections there is nothing.
Second, how to write simple query if i have only pivot table acces not database/sql? On this pivot i cant check the mdx query.

Comment: What line is erroring?

Comment: the line with:
rs.Open query, con

Comment: Have you checked `con.state` before hand.  Does the connection open ok basically?  `Debug.? con.state=adStateOpen`

Comment: Did you also check if the tablename resp. the syntax for the tablename is correct?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav with only connection i dont get any errors but i dont know if im actually connected. How to apply your code to mine correctly?

Comment: @Storax the table name from my query propably is wrong i have no clue how to import the query from pivot table and apply it in my code.

Comment: at the time of error, on the debug window, enter the code I put in comment

Comment: So the table name is wrong?  Check that your query is correct first.  Just try it with Excels data connections. :o)  Or in SQL Server.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav i added 
If con.State = adStateOpen Then
test = True
con.Close
End If
MsgBox test

after connection and it says true so im connected?

Comment: Dim rs As NEW ADODB.Recordset
You can't open a recordet until it's been initialised

Comment: @HarassedDad so i should move it to part after performing  the query in my code?

Comment: No leave it where it is but add the NEW part

Comment: @HarassedDad Well not sure how to edit my code now. Can you provide me with code and where is your suggestion?

Comment: on your third line of code add the word New between "Dim rs as " and "ADODB.recordset"

Comment: @HarassedDad The initialising is done via the set statement later on `Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset`

Comment: Nathan_Sav - Ahh! I actually missed that line even when I first saw your comment - word blindness I think, Thanks. Yes, the new isn't needed - no idea why I missed that - I must be going senile.